# Questions about this code is a very familiar to Dictionaries does. What does kind of this code called?

Tags: swift, dictionary

I just enjoy to research more things more than basics of the Swift programming, and actually notice a very familiar to dictionaries does. Would you like to explains me how does this actually means and name of those code programming, if you know?

Code Results:

```
// MARK: Dictionaries
var Weather = [String: String]()
Weather["Sunday"] = "Sunny"

// MARK: What does this with angle bracket syntax is called?
// Notice: It's seems familar to Dictionaries.
var Total_Miles = Dictionary<String, Int>()
Total_Miles["Antonio"] = 100
```

Thank you for brings a kind of help! :)

Comment: Also note: `UpperCamelCase` identifiers are reserved for types in Swift. All values should use `lowerCamelCase`. Conventionally, `snake_case` isn't used at all in Swift.

Comment: in cases, Swift will tell the error if that name value has space character, also I find other way to use _ could be useful for space character to solve the error. Maybe I could answer wrong about it, I guess. : )

Comment: Yep, so the Swift convention would be to use `weather` and `totalMiles`.

Comment: Yes but Sometimes, I prefer underscore to help to find a place where I am looking for it, but I could use that without underscore with comments to help find the place as easier. : )

Comment: That's what command+click is for.

Comment: Yeah, I found out in a few months ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[String: String]` is [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for `Dictionary<String, Int>`.

`Dictionary<String, Int>` is just a simple example of a generic type. [`Dictionary`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary) has two generic type parameters, called `Key` and `Value`.

In the general case, `Dictionary` isn't just one data type. It's like a pattern for establishing data types, one per unique set of type parameters provided as `Key` and `Value`.

`Dictionary<String, Int>` is a specific type, a `Dictionary` whose `Key` type is `String`, and whose `Value` type is `Int`.

In both cases, the trailing `()` are a call to an initializer, syntactic sugar for `[String: Int].init()` and `Dictionary<String, Int>.init()`, respectively.

Comment: This is a very simple explains! Thank you, Alexander. :-)